# Slideshow move out of content box on Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, slideshow, out

You'll see the slideshow goes to the right of the content box only on Firefox, I can't figure out what the problem is, could you help me?

http://tataviajes.com/index.php

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `clear: both;` to your `#nav` id this will force floating elements on either the left or right side to the next line